# Custom function constantly throwing an error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I wrote a custom in-cell function for having a specified data validation list only if a given cell isn't empty. Here's that function:

```
function CONDITIONALVALIDATION(sheetName,cellToCheckA1,validationCell,validationItems){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var cellValue = sheet.getRange(cellToCheckA1).getValue();
  var cellToSet = sheet.getRange(validationCell);
  cellToSet.clearDataValidations();
  if(cellValue!=""){
  var unitsRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(validationItems, true);
    cellToSet.setDataValidation(unitsRule)
  }
}
```

When I call a test function which fills the parameters for the CONDITIONALVALIDATION function and run it within the editor, I see the desired results. That function is the following:

```
function testconditional(){
  CONDITIONALVALIDATION("Front End","E12","F12",["x","y"]);
}
```

However, when I call the function as a custom in-cell function, I constantly get a

> "Formula Parse Error."

I have already ruled out syntax as a possible cause; the call to the function in my test function is the exact same as when I call it within a custom in-cell function. Save, of course, the equals sign before the function call to indicate that it is a function to be run. I also know that the function is recognized by sheets; there is no "Function nonexistant", or "#NAME?" error when the function is called within the cell.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue(s):

Javascript Array literals `[]` are not valid spreadsheet formula syntax. Try `{}` instead:

```
=CONDITIONALVALIDATION("Front End","E12","F12",{"x","y"});
```

Having said that, As written in the documentation, Custom functions can't [`.setDataValidation(unitsRule)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services)

> Spreadsheet
>
> > Read only (can use most get*() methods, but not set*()).

#### Solution:

> To use a service other than those listed above, create a custom menu that runs an Apps Script function instead of writing a custom function. A function that is triggered from a menu will ask the user for authorization if necessary and can consequently use all Apps Script services.

Answer (score 2):

Google Apps Script custom functions can't make changes on objects (Spreadsheet, Sheet, Range, etc). They only can return a value or an array of values.

Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Regarding the formula parse error message it occurs when the formula has some syntax errors that are not caught by the "regular formula syntax checker"  like having syntax errors on arrays.

As already was mentioned, one alternative is to use a custom menu. Usually an on edit trigger is not mentioned because they aren't triggered when the result of a formula changes but on some scenarios could work, like when it's expected that change is made when a used edit a cell.